# Can a digital currency be involved in Hyper Ledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Just like Bitcoin or Ethereum, can there be a digital currency involved in Hyper Ledger Fabric ?

Answer (score 3):

Since the chaincode can read and write any byte arrays and can execute any arbitrary logic implemented in Go (in the future in other languages), you can implement digital currency if you want, and make the applications that consume the chaincode - use it. But the infrastructure itself would not enforce it